# AngleSharp and XHTML round-trip

Tags: c#, parsing, anglesharp

I'm trying to parse an XHTML file using AngleSharp, make a change, then output it. However, I'm having some issues getting the output to match the input.

- If I use the XML parser and either the `XMLMarkupFormatter` or the `HtmlMarkupFormatter` I get no self-closing tags (all are `<img></img>`) and no XML declaration.
- If I use the HTML parser and the `HTMLMarkupFormatter` I get XML invalid self-closing tags (all are simply `<img>`) and no XML declaration.
- If I use the HTML parser and the `XMLMarkupFormatter` I get nice self closing tags (`<img />`), and the XML declaration - however, the XML declaration is picked up as a comment and outputted as `<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->`

Is there a way around this or do I need to write my own `MarkupFormatter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: It sounds like you need to provide your own `MarkupFormatter`.

There has been some effort to come up with an `XhtmlMarkupFormatter`, but this component has unfortunately not been realized so far. I imagine such a component may combine the serialization from both, the existing HTML and the available XML formatter.

Maybe [this issue on the AngleSharp repo](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/56) helps you.